# Populate new_hash where the unique values from old_hash are the keys, and the keys from old_hash are values, grouped into arrays.

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, enumerable

I am new to programing and am starting with Ruby.
Using .each ONLY, my challenge is to turn this:

```
animals = {
  'leopard'   => 1,
  'gorilla'   => 3,
  'hippo'     => 4,
  'zebra'     => 1,
  'lion'      => 2,
  'eagle'     => 3,
  'ostrich'   => 2,
  'alligator' => 6
}
```

Into this hash where the animals are grouped by count:

```
animals_by_count = {
   1 => ['leopard', 'zebra'],
   2 => ['lion', 'ostrich'],
   3 => ['gorilla', 'eagle'],
   4 => ['hippo'],
   6 => ['alligator']
}
```

This is my code, it is not working properly.
Again, I must use .each ONLY, I my NOT use .map .inject .select or any another method.

```
animals_by_count = {}
animals.each do |animal, count|
  animals_array = []
  if !animals_by_count.has_key?(count)
    animals_by_count[count] = animals_array << animal
  elsif animals_by_count.has_key?(count)
    animals_by_count[count] = animals_array << animal
  end

 end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as below :-

```
animals = {
  'leopard'   => 1,
  'gorilla'   => 3,
  'hippo'     => 4,
  'zebra'     => 1,
  'lion'      => 2,
  'eagle'     => 3,
  'ostrich'   => 2,
  'alligator' => 6
}

animals_by_count = {}
animals.each do |animal, count|
  if animals_by_count.has_key?(count)
    animals_by_count[count].push(animal)
  else
    animals_by_count[count] = [animal]
  end
end

animals_by_count
# => {1=>["leopard", "zebra"],
#     3=>["gorilla", "eagle"],
#     4=>["hippo"],
#     2=>["lion", "ostrich"],
#     6=>["alligator"]}
```

> Why not worked your one ?

```
animals.each do |animal, count|
  animals_array = []
# see here at every iteration, you are creating a new empty array and using it.
# animals_by_count key thus holding the last array, loosing the previous one.
```

Answer (score 2):

@Arup has explained why your code is not working, and showed you have to fix it.  I would like show you some variations and alternatives that an experienced Rubiest might used.  These fall into two categories:

- Build a new hash, adding elements of `animals` one at a time
- Use [Enmerable#goup_by](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)

**Build a new hash**

This is the approach you have taken, which @Arup fixed. Let me change Arup's code slightly:

```
h = {}
animals.each do |(name, num)|
  h[num] = [] unless h.key?(num)
  h[num] << name
end
h
  #=> {1=>["leopard", "zebra"],
  #    3=>["gorilla", "eagle"],
  #    4=>["hippo"],
  #    2=>["lion", "ostrich"], 6=>["alligator"]}
```

Whenever `h` does not contain a key `num`, we add the element `num => []` to the hash.  Then `name` is appended to the array `h[num]`.  The statement:

```
h[num] = [] unless h.key?(num)
```

is the same as

```
h[num] = h[num] || []
```

which can be combined with the next line:

```
h[num] = (h[num] || []) << name
```

and optionally written

```
(h[num] ||= []) << name
```

If we use the last of these, we would write:

```
h = {}
animals.each { |(name,num)| (h[num] ||= []) << name }
h
```

Rather than creating the empty hash, building it in the next step and the returning it after it's built, that can all be done in one line:

```
animals.each_with_object({}) { |(name,num),h| (h[num] ||= []) << name }
```

A variant of this is to replace the empty hash with the form of [Hash#new](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-c-new) that takes a block:

```
Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }
```

If this hash is accessed by a key that doesn’t correspond to a hash entry, `h` and `k` are passed to the block to allow you to create a value for the key.  Here we want that to be an empty array.  This allows us to write:

```
animals.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) { |(name,num),h|
  h[num] << name }
```

I'm not suggesting which of these approaches you should use.  They all work. The choice is yours.

[Enumerable#each_with_object](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) was introduced in Ruby v1.9.  Before that, and still now, [Enumerable#reduce](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (aka `inject`) would or can be used for this task:

```
animals.reduce({}) { |h,(name,num)| (h[num] ||= []) << name; h }
```

Notice the order of the block parameters: `|(name,num),h|` for `each_with_object`, `|h,(name,num)|` for `reduce`.  Also, when using `reduce`, the object (here `h`) must be returned to `reduce`.  That's the reason for the lonely `h` as the last statement in `reduce`'s block.

**Use `Enmerable#goup_by`**

The second common way to attack this kind of problem is to use `group_by`, which returns the following hash:

```
h = animals.group_by { |_,v| v }
  #=> {1=>[["leopard", 1], ["zebra", 1]],
  #    3=>[["gorilla", 3], ["eagle", 3]],
  #    4=>[["hippo", 4]],
  #    2=>[["lion", 2], ["ostrich", 2]],
  #    6=>[["alligator", 6]]}
```

Now all we need to do is to manipulate the hash values (e.g., change `[["leopard", 1], ["zebra", 1]]` to `["leopard", "zebra"]`.

There are a couple of ways to do this.  One is to enumerate over the hash keys and modify the values:

```
h.keys.each { |k| h[k] = h[k].map(&:first) }
h
```

Another is to build a new hash:

```
g = {}
h.each { |k,v| g[k] = v.map(&:first) }
g
```

which can also be written:

```
h.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),g| g[k] = v.map(&:first) }
```

Comment: +1 for such a detailed explanation. OP should accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
animals.each{|name,num|(h[num]||=[])<<name}
```

Comment: Please don't just post a line of code as an answer without any explanation or context. You really should the time to explain why OP's attempt failed and why this code works.